# Saving Meta in OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, emacs, terminal, meta-key

Since Terminal appeared I've saved as ~/mySrvr.term a modified stock .term file
which opens to execute an ssh to a remote server and to modify the appearance.
I have NOT been able to save "use option key as meta" for emacs-ery; there's no slot for it
in the term file and I'm reluctant to wrestle with a keyboard dictionary file.
Am I missing something simple?  How do I get option-as-meta to stick between sessions?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just set it in your Terminal preferences? Is there some reason why you don't want to use option as meta?

Answer (score 4):

If you're on Leopard open up preferences in Terminal.app.  There is a tab called Settings which is actually settings for different styles of terminal windows.  Make a copy of one of Apple's defaults and change it to your liking and make sure to select the option-as-meta radio button there.

I don't even bother opening term files now, under Leopard you can save any group of windows via the Windows menu and it saves all of their settings and and you can open these backup via the same menu. For example, I have a window group that ssh's into a server in two tabs and the third tab starts up an ssh tunnel.

Comment: In detail: go to Settings | Shell, and enter something like "ssh example.com" in the "Run Command" box.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but when I go Shell -> Export Settings and save the file as a .terminal file, there are a few lines that save my option-as-meta preference:

```
<key>useOptionAsMetaKey</key>
<true/>
```

These lines are for a .terminal preference file, not for a .term (which is pretty hard to Google for) so they may not be what you're looking for.